# Mixins in dart 2.1 - "on" keyword

Tags: dart

From:
https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-1-improved-performance-usability-9f55fca6f31a

Under Mixins:

```
mixin SomeClass<T extends SomeOtherClass>
on State<T>
implements ThirdClass
```

What is "on"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figuratively speaking **on** is the **extends** for mixins.

```
mixin A on B
```

is like

```
class A extends B
```

To choose which one to use is like to choose between composition or inheritance. [More on that composition vs inheritance thing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

### What is the difference?

```
class ExtraPowers{}

class ClassPowers extends ExtraPowers{}
mixin MixinPowers on ExtraPowers{}
```

Let's say our main character is class "C" and we want to give it some extra capabilities and powers. We can do that in two ways:

```
// e.g. inheritance
class C extends ClassPowers{}
```

or

```
// e.g. composition
class C with ExtraPowers, MixinPowers{}
```

So if we choose to **extend** we may need to comply to some requirements. And we can do that by passing arguments to *super*.

If we choose to gain powers by using **with** can't use **super** to pass requirements. The requirements are satisfied by having the same extra powers as our mixin (nothing is left hidden e.g *composition*) and that **on** keyword tells us what extra powers our mixin has. So in order to get powers from **MixinPowers** we first must get **ExtraPowers**.

```
class C with ExtraPowers, MixinPowers{}
```

In conclusion **on** just like **extends** gives access to members of another object but **on** is for mixins **extends** for classes. The difference is when you use mixin you must implement the objects after the **on** keyword.

[More info](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.1/super-mixins/feature-specification.md)

Answer (score 11):

This mixin can only be applied to classes that extend or implement `State<T>` which is effectively the state of a stateful widget.

Comment: is it possible to restrict it to more than one class? E.g. on State<T>, SomeOtherClass. I mean something like restricting generics in C#

Comment: I don't think so. The Dart language spec might have more details.

Comment: I've read it already. It only contains examples with one. I thought I might have missed out on something. Anyway, thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

```
mixin A on B {};
class Component extends B with A {}
```

Means that, for **Component**, in order to be able to use the mixin A, it must extends B.